# Getting Error while trying to fetch Facebook Ads data using OAuth2 in php (laravel)

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-ads-api, facebook-authentication

[This is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJvjK.png)

please help me what to do to resolve this.
Thank you

I had tried to fetch facebook ads data on my application to create dashboard using Oauth2 Authentication and i have use client id and secrete but after this when tried to redirect to facebook for OAuth2 Authentication then getting error as i shown in the image .

i want to resolve this so that i can fetch facebook ads data .
please help me for the same how can i resolve this.